How to interpret a limit condition
Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ is binary and $Y$ is continuous with full support..
Assume that
$$
(1) \quad \Pr(X=1, Y\geq y )=\kappa \Pr(Y\geq y) (1+r(y)),
$$
for some function $r$ such that
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}r(y)=0
$$
I have trouble interpreting this assumption. Could you help?

My thoughts and where I need your help:
I would be tempted to say that this assumption essentially means (or implies?) that
$$
(2) \quad \Pr(X=1, Y\geq y )=\kappa \Pr(Y\geq y) \quad \text{ for $y$ large},
$$
but I suspect I am making mistakes with limits. In fact, if I apply the limit to both sides of (1), I get
$$
(3)\quad \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X=1, Y\geq y )=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \kappa \Pr(Y\geq y) (1+r(y)).
$$
In (3),  $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X=1, Y\geq y )$ is not necessarily $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X=1, Y\geq \infty)$, which would be trivially zero. Similarly, $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \kappa \Pr(Y\geq y) (1+r(y))$ is not $ \kappa \Pr(Y\geq \infty) (1+r(\infty))$  which would be trivially zero as well.  So, what is (1) telling me?

Dividing equation (1) by $\Pr(Y\ge y)$, you have on the left the conditional probability of $P(X=1)$ given $\{Y\ge y\}$. Then the equation is telling you that this conditional probability tends to $\kappa$ when $y\to\infty$.

I still have a doubt related to my original question for which you kindly provided an answer. Suppose that, instead of dividing (1) by $\Pr(Y\geq y)$ as you suggest, I write (1) as $$\Pr(X=x, Y\geq y)=\kappa \Pr(Y\geq y) + \kappa\Pr(Y\geq y)r(y)$$  Then, I apply the limit on both sides $$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\Pr(X=x, Y\geq y)\=\kappa  \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(Y\geq y)  + \kappa \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\Pr(Y\geq y)r(y)\=0+\kappa \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\Pr(Y\geq y)r(y)\ = \kappa \times 0 \times 0 =0$$ which seems totally wrong... But which step is incorrect here?

@Star I guess there should be "$X=1$" instead of "$X=x$".

@AlexRavsky Thanks, sorry, I can't change it now, but you're right.

@Star Both sides of your equation go to zero when y tends to infinity. But dividing by the probability that $Y$ is greater than $y$, the limits are $\kappa$. There is nothing wrong with that.

For the notation simplicity, suppose that for each sufficiently big real $y$ we have $\Pr(Y\geq y)=f(y)$ and $\Pr(X=1, Y\geq y )=g(y)$. Then $g(y)=\kappa f(y)(1+r(y))$. If $\kappa=0$ then $g(y)=0$, so we assume $\kappa\ne 0$. When $y$ tends to the infinity then $f(y)$ tends to the zero. So $g(y)$ tends to the zero too. But if $f(y)>0$ for each real $y$ then the difference $g(y)-\kappa f(y)$ tends to the zero even faster, namely, as $\kappa f(y)\cdot r(y)$. Indeed, we have
$\frac {f(y)}{f(y)}=1\to 1$, $\frac {g(y)}{f(y)}=\kappa (1+r(y))\to\kappa$, but $\frac{g(y)-\kappa f(y)}{f(y)}=r(y)\to 0$.

(a) following your answer, can I say that (1) states something "stronger" than $$\lim \Pr(X=1, Y\geq y)= \lim \Pr(Y\geq y)=0$$? (b) In your answer, should it be "... faster, namely, as $\kappa \Pr(Y\geq y)r(y)$"? (c) why the rate of $\kappa \Pr(Y\geq y)r(y)$ (or $\kappa \Pr(X=1, Y\geq y)r(y)$ if your answer has no typo) is faster than the rate of $\Pr(X=1, Y\geq y)$ and $\Pr(Y\geq y)$?

@Star Sorry for the delay with the answer. For (a) I guess so, because the equality you mention is trivial. (b) You are right. Thank you for the attention and sorry for the misprint. I corrected it. (c) I updated the answer.
